# Console app converted to Azure Webjob not able to wite to a file location mentioned in app.config

Tags: azure, file, logging, console-application, webjob

I'm converting a console app running on a windows server to an Azure Web job. This console application has references to the .txt log file location in app.config.

I was able to deploy the webjob, but when I run the webjob, I get the below error as the webjob is not able to get to this path, which is on the server. 
Access to the path 'C:\Jobs\logs\Log 4_27_2020.txt' is denied.

What is the solution for this ?

Also, the same console app also has the file layout defined in .xml format as:

How can I get the webjob to reference this location?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to the C drive.  The folder structure starts at D:\home and is mapped to the %HOME% environment variable.

[Understanding the Azure App Service file system](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system)

Comment: Thank you for the response. How can I define the file in the D:\home folder? My requirement is to create a log file in this location. Also, the console app uses an xml file layout to map the CSV when it reads it. Where can I define this input XML file? currently its defined in the app.config as <add key="FormatFile" value="C:\jobs\Import\formatfile.xml"/>

Comment: Why can't you deploy your app.config file along your app and read the key like you're doing right now?  You can also store that value in a application setting.